# Redirect www.example.com/some-path/example/ to www.example.com/some-path/?ABC=123

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a path like this: from `www.example.com/some-path/sg/` to `www.example.com/some-path/`

But I need some way of identifying this traffic such a parameter, ideally: `www.example.com/some-path/?ls=sg`. Is this possible using htaccess/mod_rewrite?

What I have tried is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /sg/(.*) /$1?ls=SG7
```

Comment: Please do share your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I tried:
RedirectMatch 301 /sg/(.*) /$1?ls=SG7
..but this just redirects to the route, but it does include the parameter so not too far off. I just need to keep the rest of the path though.

Comment: Is `sg` parameter is always fixed to be passed in any kind of url? Please confirm once, since you are redirecting to url `www.example.com/some-path/` where it will not be in url so htaccess will not come to know if its hidden once in front end. Please confirm once.

Comment: No, sg is not in all urls, just some. So when it is present, remove it and pass a parameter so i can do something else off the back of it

Comment: Ok so url `www.example.com/some-path/?ls=sg` you are hitting in browser? And you want to change it to `www.example.com/some-path/sg/`? Please confirm once

Comment: No, when i go to www.example.com/some-path/sg/ I want to redirect to www.example.com/some-path/?ls=sg (removing the /sg/ part and adding a parameter ...so the opposite of what you said). Thanks :)

Comment: So you want to change url in browser to `www.example.com/some-path/?ls=sg` url? Or in backend it should be like that?

Comment: In the browser please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, samples please try following htaccess Rules file.
Make sure to place them at the top of your htaccess rules file.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##To look for sg here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} sg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /$1/?ls=$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: That almost works, thank you. Just one issue when there is more than 1 directory before it. I.e. www.example.com/some-path/another-path/sg/

Comment: @FullStackMedia, ok sure, could you please do test my edited code once and let me know how it goes? cheers.

Comment: Sorry, it is nearly there but I am still retaining the /sg/ in the redirected url, I need to strip that out or it causes an error. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: http://example.com/example/example/john-doe/sg/ gets rewritten to http://example.com/example/example/john-doe/sg/?ls=sg which is almost correct. I just need to remove that /sg/ section from the new url.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sg
RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]*)(?:/[^/]*))/(.*) /$1/$2?ls=sg [R=301,NE,L] is what I currently have in place. In the rewrite condition is it possible to be more specific and look for /sg/ before it executes the rule?

Comment: @FullStackMedia, Sorry I slept the time you commented. I have edited my code to remove sd(last part in uri) and to look for `sd ` in url and apply rules to only that url, please test it and let me know how it goes?